# Collapsing The Navigation Bar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

i want to make a Collapsing  Navigation Bar in bootstrap. but my code is not working  :( below is my code. i cant figure it out where is am wrong.  Please help me

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></span> About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span> Blog</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems to collapse fine.  [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/JDdKU26A1j).  Right side, click on the mobile phone icon.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you didn't include jQuery on your code that's why it is not functioning. Always remeber that jQuery is required by all Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins to make it function (read the Bootstrap [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#whats-included) to also see which versions of jQuery are compatible).

The proper way to include jQuery is right before the Bootstrap's JavaScripts file  (on top). And to make your page loads faster, place your JavaScripts at the end of your page contents, right before the closing `</body>` tag.

> You can have all jQuery versions listed [here](https://code.jquery.com/jquery/) (only the Core ones).

**The Snippet**

```
<!-- jQuery must come first -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- And below here is the Bootstrap JS file(s) -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Your code is actually fine without errors. Here's the [demo](http://jsbin.com/fuquvupixa/edit?output) of your code.